# Making Combination from lists using itertools

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

```
import itertools
a = [[2, 3], [3, 4]]
b = [[5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
c = [[11, 12], [13, 14]]
d = [[15, 16], [17, 18]]
e = [[12,16],[13,17],[14,18],[15,19]]

q=[]
q=list(itertools.combinations((a, b, b,c, c, d,e),7)
print q
```

How would I go about using the combination function from itertools properly to use list a one time, b 2 times without replacement, c 2 times without replacement, and d and e one time each?

```
[[[2, 3],[5, 6],[7, 8],[11, 12],[13, 14],[15, 16],[12,16]], 
[[2, 3],[5, 6],[7, 8],[11, 12],[13, 14],[15, 16],[13,17]],
[[2, 3],[5, 6],[7, 8],[11, 12],[13, 14],[15, 16],[14,18]],
[[2, 3],[5, 6],[7, 8],[11, 12],[13, 14],[15, 16],[15,19]], 
[[2, 3],[5, 6],[7, 8],[11, 12],[13, 14],[15, 16],[12,16]],...
[[3, 4],[7, 8],[9, 10],[11, 12], [13, 14],[17, 18],[15,19]]]
```

Comment: Are the two draws from `b` with or without replacement?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you want here (can you give the first few example outputs or something to be sure?), but if you wrap `itertools.combinations` in `list` for a decent number of inputs, you're almost guaranteed to blow your memory. The number of outputs grows at roughly `O(n!)` (factorial growth); you're usually expected to iterate the combinations one by one, not store them all at once.

Comment: Without replacement,

Comment: Could you show us the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for a combination of [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product): Use `combinations` to get the possible combinations without replacement for the repeated lists, then use `product` to combine all those combinations. You can put the lists and counts in two lists, `zip` those lists, and use a generator expression to get all the combinations.

```
from itertools import product, combinations, chain
lists = [a,b,c,d,e]
counts = [1,2,2,1,1]
combs = product(*(combinations(l, c) for l, c in zip(lists, counts)))
```

For this example, the `combs` generator has 48 elements, among others:

```
[(([2, 3],), ([5, 6], [7, 8]), ([11, 12], [13, 14]), ([15, 16],), ([12, 16],)),
 ...
 (([2, 3],), ([5, 6], [7, 8]), ([11, 12], [13, 14]), ([17, 18],), ([15, 19],)),
 (([2, 3],), ([5, 6], [9, 10]),([11, 12], [13, 14]), ([15, 16],), ([12, 16],)),
 ...
 (([3, 4],), ([5, 6], [7, 8]), ([11, 12], [13, 14]), ([15, 16],), ([12, 16],)),
 ...
 (([3, 4],), ([5, 6], [7, 8]), ([11, 12], [13, 14]), ([17, 18],), ([15, 19],)),
 ...
 (([3, 4],), ([7, 8], [9, 10]),([11, 12], [13, 14]), ([17, 18],), ([15, 19],))]
```

If you want [flattened lists](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/1639625), just [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) them:

```
>>> combs = (list(chain(*p)) for p in product(*(combinations(l, c) for l, c in zip(lists, counts))))
>>> list(combs)
[[[2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 8], [11, 12], [13, 14], [15, 16], [12, 16]],
 ...
 [[3, 4], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12], [13, 14], [17, 18], [15, 19]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated given clarification of expected output**:

[You want `itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
itertools.product(a, b, b, c, c, c, c, d, e)
```

Which will pick one element from each of its arguments on each iteration, cycling the rightmost element the fastest, leftmost slowest.

You can use extended argument unpacking to express the repetition of certain arguments a little more obviously in Python 3:

```
itertools.product(a, *[b]*2, *[c]*4, d, e)
```

Or use [tobias_k's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39520252/364696) for more general repetition of sequences (that will also work on Py2).

Comment: But this will not draw one from a, two from b, etc., but just 9 from all together.

Comment: @tobias_k: I answered before the OP clarified the precise usage. Will fix.

Answer (score 1):

What your are trying to achieve is the `Cartesian product of input iterables` and not the combinations of the item present in the list. Hence you have to use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) instead.

In case repetition is allowed among the lists which used more than once, answer is simple:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> b = [3,4]
>>> [i for i in itertools.product(a, b, b)]
[(1, 3, 3), (1, 3, 4), (1, 4, 3), (1, 4, 4), (2, 3, 3), (2, 3, 4), (2, 4, 3), (2, 4, 4)]
```

But in case `repetition is not allowed` within the same lists, it will become little nasty and you need to combine the above answer with [`combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) and [`chain()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) (same as mentioned by [tobias_k](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1639625/tobias-k)). This code will give the list of all `combinations`:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product, combinations
>>> lists, counts = [a, b], [1, 2]  # to track that a is to be used once, and b twice
>>> list(list(chain(*p)) for p in product(*(combinations(l, c) for l, c in zip(lists, counts))))
[[1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

However, in case you need permutations instead of combinations, you have to update the above code with [`permutations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
>>> from itertools import chain, product, permutations
>>> list(list(chain(*p)) for p in product(*(permutations(l, c) for l, c in zip(lists, counts))))
[[1, 3, 4], [1, 4, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 4, 3]]
```

Comment: Not entirely clear from the question, but I think then the last line in the expected output should contain `[13, 14], [11, 12]` instead of `[11, 12], [13, 14]`.

Comment: @tobias_k On looking at his sample output, I believe he needs cartesian product of the lists. Updated the answer with simple example. And I agree with you, the input params OP provided are too huge and gives no clear insight of his intention. Simpler example would be helpful

Comment: order doesnt matter

Comment: @WilliamBernard : In that case it is @ tobias_k answer you should be marked as accepted. As I have mentioned this after he answered

Comment: @WilliamBernard: It was not cleared from the sample you provided in the question. So, I mentioned all the possible solutions :P

Comment: I apologize, but without replacement is an important distinction I didnt mention as well as order not mattering